# Newlfm horizontal line too low on second page

Tags: newlfm

I'm using the newlfm document class and find myself bothered by the problem that the lower horizontal line (which on the first page is some centimeters above the end of the page) starts being exactly at the lower edge of the page starting with page 2. 
Any ideas how to change that?
Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,stdletter,dateno, sigleft]{newlfm}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}

\widowpenalty=1000
\clubpenalty=1000

\newlfmP{headermarginskip=20pt}
\newlfmP{sigsize=50pt}
\newlfmP{dateskipafter=20pt}
\newlfmP{addrfromphone}
\newlfmP{addrfromemail}
\PhrPhone{Phone}
\PhrEmail{Email}

\namefrom{}
\addrfrom{}
\phonefrom{}
\emailfrom{}

\addrto{}

\greetto{}
\closeline{nmnmnmnmnm}
\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}
Text\newpage text
\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your example code produces only one page; please amend it so that it produces more than one page and demonstrates the problem you've found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply adding `\Cfooter` (even with an empty argument, if no footer is desired in the first page) prevents the undesired behaviour:

```
\documentclass[10pt,stdletter,dateno, sigleft]{newlfm}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}

\widowpenalty=1000
\clubpenalty=1000

\newlfmP{headermarginskip=20pt}
\newlfmP{sigsize=50pt}
\newlfmP{dateskipafter=20pt}
\newlfmP{addrfromphone}
\newlfmP{addrfromemail}
\PhrPhone{Phone}
\PhrEmail{Email}

\namefrom{}
\addrfrom{}
\phonefrom{}
\emailfrom{}

\addrto{}

\greetto{}
\closeline{nmnmnmnmnm}

\Cfooter{}

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}
Text\newpage text
\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

[image]